# PCManFM "Create New" not working

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, pcmanfm

I'm attempting to create a new file in PCManFM. When I right-click and choose "Create New>Folder", or any other template, the context menu closes and no new file is created. Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: After trying again a few times, it seems to work, though it still takes a number of tries in order to work.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I'm going through old and unanswered questions in my attempt to get some of them squared away. If you go this resolved then please let us know how you did so - that way the repository of knowledge is more complete. If you didn't get this resolved and are still having this issue could you run `gksudo pcmanfm` from the terminal and try to make a new file/folder/whatnot? When you do so, copy the errors (if applicable) and add those to your question and we may be able to resolve this. Thanks and, again, sorry that nobody knew the answer to your question.